# Select ID from database when user selects value in drop down

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I have a table which contains `ID` and `DOC_DESC`. When user selects the `DOC_DESC` from the drop down and submits, `ID` of that particular row should be printed.

I have written following code:

```
<?php    
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbtest");
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID,DOC_DESC FROM document_type_master");
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $select= '<select name="select">';
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       $select.='<option value="'.$rs['ID'].'">'.$rs['DOC_DESC'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo " "; //ID should be printed here
}
?>
```

I am also getting error as:
    mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the connection instance to mysql_query(). So the result resource is not available for the mysql_num_rows() function.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbtest",$link);
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID,DOC_DESC FROM document_type_master",$link);
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $select= '<select name="select">';
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       $select.='<option value="'.$rs['ID'].'">'.$rs['DOC_DESC'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is still says: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: I just updated db connection instance for mysql_select_db(). So update that line too and check...

Answer (score 0):

J**ust do as -**

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID,DOC_DESC FROM document_type_master");  
echo "<select name='select'>";
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
          {
             echo "<option value='$row['ID']'>".$row['DOC_DESC']."</option>";
          }
echo "</select";
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   echo $_POST['select];
}
```

Comment: It says: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: use mysql_error() function to get proper error message.

Comment: All mysql functions like mysql_num_rows() and mysql_fetch_array() gives error as expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: problem may be in your table and its fields. just check your table may be the white space will be issue.

Comment: Thanks buddy found my mistake.

Comment: Did you get output?